# Color different curves with a gradient

Tags: plotting, color

My code:

```
t = Table[a/(1 + Exp[- x]) + 1.72/(1 + Exp[- y]) - 1.1 == 0, {a, -7.0, 7.0, 
0.3}];
ContourPlot[t, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10} ]
```

The output is like this:

[image]

But I want the curves to be colored in a gradient, like GrayTones or different shades of red, say.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ContourStyle -> Table[GrayLevel[i/47], {i, 0, 46, 1}]` ,

where there are 47 values governed by `{a, -7.0, 7.0, 0.3}`.

Comment: Why 52 and not 50?  :)

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution:

```
t = Table[a/(1 + Exp[- x]) + 1.72/(1 + Exp[- y]) - 1.1 == 0, {a, -7.0, 7.0, 
0.3}];
t2 = Table[Hue[i], {i, 0, 1.0, 0.015}];
ContourPlot[t, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10} , ContourStyle -> t2]
```

The result looks like this:

[image]